# Optimizate this solution about finding shortest paths between two stops in bus network

Tags: python, algorithm

This problem is from CodeEval open challenges, indeed I tried many methods to work out a faster solution to this problem,  but the result is just "time exceeded". The link to the problem is as follows: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/134/. Then my solution is as follows:

```
import sys
import profile
import array
import collections

def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.strip().split('; ') 
            src, dst = map(int, data[0].strip('()').split(','))
            routes = [map(int, r.split('=')[1].strip('[]').split(',')) for r in data[1:]]
            #create a graph with the routes 
            #print "routes: %s" % routes
            start = 0
            g = {}
            node_ref = {}
            for r in routes:
                rlen = len(r)
                for i in range(rlen):
                    if i < rlen-1:
                        if start+i not in g:
                            g[start+i] = [(start+i+1, 7)]
                        else:
                            g[start+i].append((start+i+1, 7))
                        if start+i+1 not in g:
                            g[start+i+1] = [(start+i, 7)]
                        else:
                            g[start+i+1].append((start+i, 7))
                    if r[i] in node_ref:
                        for node in node_ref[r[i]]:
                            g[start+i].append((node, 12))
                            g[node].append((start+i, 12))
                    if r[i] not in node_ref:
                        node_ref[r[i]] = [start+i]
                    elif start+i not in node_ref[r[i]]:
                        node_ref[r[i]].append(start+i)
                start += rlen
            #print "create graph: %s" % g
            ans = 100000000
            #print node_ref[src]
            for s in node_ref[src]:
                visited = [False] * start
                costs = [100000000] * start
                costs[s] = 0
                get_cost(s, g, visited, costs)
                res = min([costs[node] for node in node_ref[dst]])
                if res < ans:ans = res
            if ans == 100000000:
                print "None"
            else:
                print ans
    sys.exit(0)

def get_cost(src, g, visited, costs):
    nq = collections.deque()
    nq.append(src)
    costs[src] = 0
    while nq:
        curnode = nq.popleft()
        visited[curnode] = True
        for (node, w) in g[curnode]:
            if not visited[node]:
                nq.append(node)
                if costs[node] > costs[curnode] + w:
                    costs[node] = costs[curnode] + w 

def test():
    g = {0: [(1, 7)], 1: [(0, 7), (2, 7)], 2: [(1, 7)], 3: [(4, 7), (11, 12)], 4: [(3, 7), (5, 7)], 5: [(4, 7), (6, 7)], 6: [(5, 7), (7, 7)], 7: [(6, 7)], 8: [(9, 7)], 9: [(8, 7), (10, 7)], 10: [(9, 7), (11, 7)], 11: [(10, 7), (3, 12)]}
    visited = [False] * 12
    costs = [100000000] * 12
    s = 3
    get_cost(s, g, visited, costs)
    print "src %d, costs: %s" % (s, costs) 
    #get_cost(3, g, visited, costs)
    #print "src 3, costs: %s" % 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #profile.run("main();")
    main()
```

Can anyone provide some advice for doing optimization to this solution?

Comment: The easy way to do this is to copy the same code you want to optimize then analyze it to find what can be optimized, like common patterns of code like merging some loops or using a constant instead of parts that never change in a calculation or doing a calculation in a different way that cost less time, or use more space to win time, use some data structures to provide a ready data access for O(1)s

Comment: Yeah, I've tried your advice. But it may be the problem that costs time especially the function **get_simple_paths** which may take exponential time to work. Maybe there should be better solution to this problem instead of this one.

Comment: if you start from a code, you have the same time, if you modify something in that code and get more time, then that change is wrong, revert-back and try something different .. otherwise what you are asking for is not optimization - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Comment: Use Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The problem challenge you referenced seems to ask for the minimum length path if particular stops are included in the path. This can be done actually a lot faster than enumerating all simple paths in between a pair of stops. As a comment suggests, use Dijskra's algorithm with multiple starting points to get the lengths of shortest paths in between stops. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Yeah, you're right. And I try Dijskra's algorithm to solve this problem but time still exceeded. I have changed my code in the question. Maybe this time I really need do optimization.